# Electron-builder uses wrong filename in https request when trying to fetch the latest release

Tags: javascript, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I am building an application in electron and currently I'm trying to implement electron-builders [autoUpdate](https://www.electron.build/auto-update). I have one private repository with my source code and one public repository where I want to release the updated artifacts of my app.

The process looks like the folliwing:

1. Install v1 of app on computer
2. Build v2 of app
3. Publish v2 of app on github
4. Open v1 of app on computer -> starts downloading newer version

My application is able to recognise that there is a new release published on github but when it tries to download it generates the wrong url. I get the following error message

> error Cannot download "https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/v2/application-**1**-universal-mac.zip", status 404:

To me the problem seems to be that in the request the wrong version number is being used. It uses the artifact name "application-1-universal-mac.zip" instead of "application-2-universal-mac.zip" which is uploaded.

In package.json I have tried to change:

```
"build": {
   "artifactName": "appName.${ext}",
   "executableName": "lol",
   "buildVersion": "400",
   "productName": "app",  
 }
```

which changes the name of the file but in the request it always uses the default

`"node-app-${version}.${ext}"`

Does anyone have a clue which variable electron-builder is looking at when generating file name in the request?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Upon noticing that the path is generated wrongly, you have modified the `package.json`, I understand? If so, you have made sure to rebuild and reinstall v1 of your application (with the changes included) on your testing machine, right?

Comment: Thank you very much! You are correct, I changed version number in `package.json` and some random visual stuff to see that the update actually did something. And yes, I've done it a couple of times. The thing is I would prefer to not have the version number at all in my request.